# Transpose a data set

Tags: r

I want to transpose data sets similar to `my.data` below and then sum the rows.

```
my.data <- "landuse units year county.a  county.b  county.c  county.d 
            apple   acres 2010     0         2         4         6 
            pear    acres 2010    10        20        30        40
            peach   acres 2010   500       400       300       200"

my.data2 <- read.table(textConnection(my.data), header = T)
my.data2
```

The desired output is:

```
 counties all.fruit
 county.a       510
 county.b       422
 county.c       334
 county.d       246
```

I can do this with the code below.  However, the following code seems like it must be enormous overkill.  I am hoping there is a much simpler solution.

```
# transpose the data set

tmy.data2 <- t(my.data2)
tmy.data2 <- as.data.frame(tmy.data2)

# assign row names to the data set

my.rows <- row.names(tmy.data2)

transposed.data <- cbind(my.rows, tmy.data2)
transposed.data

# extract numbers to obtain row sums

fruit.data <- as.data.frame(transposed.data[4:dim(transposed.data)[1], 2:dim(transposed.data)[2]])

fruit.data2 <- as.matrix(fruit.data)

fruit.data3 <- matrix(as.numeric(fruit.data2), nrow=( dim(fruit.data2)[1] ),  byrow=F)

# sum fruit by county

all.fruit <- rowSums(fruit.data3, na.rm=T)

# create row names for summed fruit data

counties <- my.rows[4:length(my.rows)]

almost.final.data <- cbind(counties, all.fruit)

really.final.data <- as.data.frame(almost.final.data)

really.final.data[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(really.final.data[,2]))
really.final.data

str(really.final.data)
```

Thank you for any suggestions.  I can use the code above, but view this request as an opportunity to greatly improve my programming.

Comment: Why not just `colSums(my.data2[, 4:7])`? (That would get a named vector but it would be easy to transform it into a data frame). Is the real problem more complicated than that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I guess once I started thinking in terms of row sums I focused in on that to the point of not even thinking of column sums.

Comment: If I could, I'd give you +10 for showing what you tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just subset the `"county"` columns, sum them, and create a data.frame using the results:

```
out <- colSums(my.data2[,grepl("county",colnames(my.data2))])
out2 <- data.frame(counties=names(out), all.fruit=out,
          row.names=NULL, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 9):

Why can't you just add the columns instead?

```
colSums(my.data2[, 4:7])
```

or

```
library(plyr)
numcolwise(sum)(my.data2)
  year county.a county.b county.c county.d
1 6030      510      422      334      246
>
```

That said, if you want to re organize there are many choices.  The `reshape2` package provides pleasant syntax:

```
library(reshape2)
> my.data.melt <- melt(my.data2, id.vars=c('units', 'year', 'landuse'))
> my.data.melt
   units year landuse variable value
1  acres 2010   apple county.a     0
2  acres 2010    pear county.a    10
3  acres 2010   peach county.a   500
4  acres 2010   apple county.b     2
5  acres 2010    pear county.b    20
6  acres 2010   peach county.b   400
7  acres 2010   apple county.c     4
8  acres 2010    pear county.c    30
9  acres 2010   peach county.c   300
10 acres 2010   apple county.d     6
11 acres 2010    pear county.d    40
12 acres 2010   peach county.d   200
```

I would then use `plyr`:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(my.data.melt, .(variable), summarise, all.fruit=sum(value))
  variable all.fruit
1 county.a       510
2 county.b       422
3 county.c       334
4 county.d       246
>
```

You can also do this using base R `aggregate` or the `data.table` package.

## data.table

```
> library(data.table)
> my.data.melt <- as.data.table(melt(my.data2, id.vars=c('units', 'year', 'landuse')))
> my.data.melt[,list(all.fruit = sum(value)), by = variable]
   variable all.fruit
1: county.a       510
2: county.b       422
3: county.c       334
4: county.d       246
```

or if you wanted it to stay in *wide* format

```
> DT <- as.data.table(my.data2)
> DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols = grep("county",names(DT))])
   county.a county.b county.c county.d
1:      510      422      334      246

# NB: This needs v1.8.3. Before that, an as.data.table() call was required as
# the lapply(.SD,...) used to return a named list in this no grouping case.
```

## aggregate

```
> aggregate(value~variable, my.data.melt, sum)
  variable value
1 county.a   510
2 county.b   422
3 county.c   334
4 county.d   246
```

Comment: @mnel I made 3 changes to your data.table edit: i) no need to wrap the result of `lapply` with `as.data.table` (in fact that will slow things down dramatically as it prevents optimization) ii) `T` changed to `TRUE` to avoid problems if a variable name `T` exists anywhere (particularly if `T` is the value `FALSE`) and iii) avoided one repetition of `DT` variable name by using `grep(...,value=TRUE)`. Just minor changes though.

Comment: @mnel Oh, hang on, there's no grouping - was that why? I'm confused now. Perhaps revert my changes then. Just realised that `value=TRUE` bit can be removed too as `.SDcols` accepts column numbers.

Comment: @mnel and Matthew Dowle, thanks for the edits!  The answer is much more complete now.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewDowle - I'm always learning from your edits! - The lack of grouping was the reason - it didn't return a `data.table`. It does if you wrap the result in `do.call(data.table,...)`

Comment: @mnel No problem, I'm learning too: there seems to be an inconsistenty in return types in the no grouping case doesn't there so I've raised [Bug#2263](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2263&group_id=240&atid=975). In the meantime I don't see why `do.call` is needed though, why not just `as.data.table`. Either as you had it originally in `j`, or at the start of the line.

Comment: Justin, @mnel, bug#2263 now fixed in v1.8.3 and answer updated.